# "stats overview" feature using tools like bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-sass

http://itjobsco.com/

I have stumbled upon an interesting feature on this website when you scroll down that they have called "stats overview" which briefly displays data encircled, but am not sure which tools did they use to achieve that and wasn't able to reach them about it.
Would someone have an idea where to find a resource about it? Or just how to achieve the same result?

Comment: you mean render a circle with an icon in it? you can create circles like that using the css3 border-radius attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Firebug or IE Developer Tools to inspect the circles, you see that they just use some CSS to create the circles:

```
.wpjobus-stat-circle {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 80px;
    -moz-border-radius: 80px;
    border-radius: 80px;
    background-color: #16a085;
}
```